# The graph and sign of $p_n-\operatorname{ali}(n)$, where $p_n$ is the $n$-th prime and $\operatorname{ali}(n)$ the inverse of the logarithmic integral

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics

I'm inspired in [1] to ask the following question. My problem is that I have not an implementation of the inverse of the logarithmic integral $\operatorname{Li}(x)=\int_2^x\frac{dt}{\log t}$, that will be denoted in this post as  $$\operatorname{ali}(x)$$ for real numbers $x\geq 2$.

> **Question.** A) Do you know a site or article showing a graph for $$p_n-\operatorname{ali}(n)$$
>   for integers $1\leq n\leq N$ for samples of the integer $N$ enough large ($N=10^3$, $N=10^6$ and/or $N=10^9$)? In case that isn't in the literature can you show a such of these graphs for $N$ a large integer?
>
> B) Do you know if it is possible to prove that the sign of the graph for $$p_n-\operatorname{ali}(n)$$  changes infinitely often when $1\leq n$ runs over positive integers? **Many thanks.**

I don't know if the second question is obvious from Littlewood's theorem (see [2]), or it is required to add details.

### References:

[1] Juan Arias de Reyna and Jérémy Toulisse, *The* $n$-th *prime asymptotically*, Journal de Théorie des Nombres de Bordeaux, Volume: 25, Issue: 3 (2013).

[2] [The section *Skewes's_numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewes%27s_number#Skewes's_numbers) from the Wikipedia *Skewes's number*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to (B) is yes, at least conditionally. The sign of $p_n-\mathop{\rm ali}(n)$ is determined by the sign of $\pi(p_n) - \mathop{\rm li}(p_n)$ (other than the negligible possibility that one equals $0$ while the other is tiny and nonzero). The logarithmic density of those primes $p$ for which $\pi(p) > \mathop{\rm li}(p)$ is known, conditionally, to be strictly between $0$ and $1$, which in particular implies infinitely many sign changes. See [my paper "Primes in prime number races" with Lichtman and Pomerance](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~gerg/index.shtml?abstract=PPNR).

Since $\pi(x)-\mathop{\rm li}(x)$ is unconditionally known to change sign infinitely often, it would be interesting to try to prove the OP's statement unconditionally. We certainly used more than the existence of sign changes: we used the fact that for almost all $x$, the difference is not very close to $0$ (which is implicit in the existence of the limiting logarithmic distribution of the normalized difference).

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and references.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a discrete plot of $p_n-ali(n)$ for $0<n\le 10^9$ in steps of $\Delta n=10^6$ where $ali(n)$ is computed to the nearest $\frac{1}{10}$ .

[image: discrete plot of p_n-ali(n)]

---

I used the following Mathematica code to compute $ali(n)$.

**li2[x_] := LogIntegral[x] - LogIntegral[2]**

**ali[x_] := 
 Block[{aliEst = 2^Floor[Log[2, x]], aliDelta}, aliDelta = aliEst/2; 
  While[Abs[li2[aliEst] - x] >= 1/10, 
   If[li2[aliEst] < x, 
    If[li2[aliEst + aliDelta] < x, aliEst = aliEst + aliDelta, 
     aliDelta = aliDelta/2], 
    If[li2[aliEst] > x, 
     If[li2[aliEst - aliDelta] > x, aliEst = aliEst - aliDelta, 
      aliDelta = aliDelta/2]]]]; aliEst]**

---

Here are some tabular results intended to aid in verification of the correctness of the results illustrated in the discrete plot above.

$\begin{array}{ccccc}
 n & p_n & ali(n) & p_n-ali(n) & n-li2(ali(n)) \\
 100000000 & 2038074743 & 2038024446 & 50297 & 0.0423825 \\
 200000000 & 4222234741 & 4222152050 & 82691 & 0.0122003 \\
 300000000 & 6461335109 & 6461224032 & 111077 & 0.0401844 \\
 400000000 & 8736028057 & 8735937634 & 90423 & 0.053978 \\
 500000000 & 11037271757 & 11037135192 & 136565 & 0.0957046 \\
 600000000 & 13359555403 & 13359426788 & 128615 & 0.0730399 \\
 700000000 & 15699342107 & 15699252840 & 89267 & 0.0502884 \\
 800000000 & 18054236957 & 18054084488 & 152469 & 0.099884 \\
 900000000 & 20422213579 & 20422031584 & 181995 & 0.0438209 \\
 1000000000 & 22801763489 & 22801627438 & 136051 & 0.0674243 \\
\end{array}$

---

Here's another table that displays results for a wider range of values of $n$
than above.

$\begin{array}{ccccc}
 n & p_n & ali(n) & p_n-ali(n) & n-li2(ali(n)) \\
 10 & 29 & \frac{47}{2} & \frac{11}{2} & 0.00269857 \\
 100 & 541 & 495 & 46 & 0.0564974 \\
 1000 & 7919 & 7772 & 147 & 0.0389036 \\
 10000 & 104729 & 104281 & 448 & 0.0732478 \\
 100000 & 1299709 & 1298186 & 1523 & 0.0826652 \\
 1000000 & 15485863 & 15479083 & 6780 & 0.0408599 \\
 10000000 & 179424673 & 179415210 & 9463 & 0.0592949 \\
 100000000 & 2038074743 & 2038024446 & 50297 & 0.0423825 \\
 1000000000 & 22801763489 & 22801627438 & 136051 & 0.0674243 \\
 10000000000 & 252097800623 & 252097160040 & 640583 & 0.0561028 \\
 100000000000 & 2760727302517 & 2760725937336 & 1365181 & 0.013855 \\
 1000000000000 & 29996224275833 & 29996219470276 & 4805557 & 0.0131836 \\
\end{array}$

Comment: Many thanks I am going to study it, is very nice and a great contribution.

Comment: The tabular results also are very good, for example the last row. Sure that it encourage to other users or persons to study the article [1] from References. Again thanks, ins't required a response.